# Вычитание словарей (фильтрация)

Tags: python, dict

Есть 2 словаря

```
dic1 = {
    'NAME': 'JACK',
    'AGE': '20',
    'ID': '10',
    'FK_ID': '35',
    'CONST_ID': '141',
    'CODE_SK': 'LAST'
}

dic2 = {
'CODE': 'ID, FK_ID',
'CONST': 'CONST_ID'
}
```

Нужно из первого словаря (dic1) исключить пары ключ/значение, которые есть во втором словаре как значение (dic2), при этом значение во втором словаре могут быть через запятую, которые в первом являются ключом.
Должно получится так:

```
dic3 = {
    'NAME': 'JACK',
    'AGE': '20',
    'CODE_SK': 'LAST'
}
```

Пробовал словарь преобразовать в set и вычитать, но такой метод не сработал.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Предлагаю сначала сгенерировать список ключей, которые должны быть удалены из словаря. А потом отфильтровать ключи словаря по условию.

Для получения списка ключей можно проитерировать значения словаря и разделить каждое по запятой с помощью метода [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split). Лишние пробельные символы можно удалить с помощью [`strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip).

***Пример:***

```py
# ['ID', 'FK_ID', 'CONST_ID']
keys = [subkey.strip() for value in dic2.values() for subkey in value.split(',')]

result = {key: value for key, value in dic1.items() if key not in keys}
print(result)
```

***stdout:***

```py
{'NAME': 'JACK', 'AGE': '20', 'CODE_SK': 'LAST'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Еще это можно сделать через удаление ключей из словаря (или его копии, если оригинал надо сохранить):

```
for v in dic2.values():
    for k in v.split(','):
        del dic1[k.strip()]
```

Правда если в `dic2` будут ключи, которых нет в `dic1` код выдаст ошибку. Это можно обойти если вместо `del` использовать `pop`. То есть примерно так:

```
dic2 = {'CODE': 'ID, FK_ID',
        'CONST': 'CONST_ID, test_key'}

[dic1.pop(k.strip(), None) for v in dic2.values() for k in v.split(',')]

print(dic1)  # {'NAME': 'JACK', 'AGE': '20', 'CODE_SK': 'LAST'}
```

Такой способ может быть оправдан если `dic1` содержит большое количество ключей и вместо того, чтобы проверять в цикле каждый ключ можно пройти циклом по `dic2` и удалить совпадения.